# Repository not extending JpaRepository

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm new to using JPA, I am reading tutorials online and all of them extend from JPARespository like below

from this page

https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-jpa-hibernate-postgresql-restful-crud-api-example/

```
package com.example.postgresdemo.repository;

import com.example.postgresdemo.model.Answer;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface AnswerRepository extends JpaRepository<Answer, Long> {
    List<Answer> findByQuestionId(Long questionId);
}
```

But in my project Eclipse complains with the following

```
The type JpaRepository<Property,Long> cannot be the superclass of PropertyRepository; a superclass must be a class
```

Below is my class

```
package realestate.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import realestate.model.Property;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public class PropertyRepository extends JpaRepository<Property, Long> {


}
```

Comment: Note that the main benefit of Spring Data is that you don't have to write an implementing class for your `AnswerRepository`; Spring does that automatically for you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Basically JPA Repositories are interfaces.

In your code you declared a class and extending it with an interface.
A Class can implement an interface, but not extends it.

So please change Class declaration to an interface as below.

```
@Repository
public class PropertyRepository extends JpaRepository<Property, Long> {    

}
```

to

```
@Repository
public interface PropertyRepository extends JpaRepository<Property, Long> {
    
}
```

Comment: You can't implement interface with interface just edit it to class.

Comment: @sanjeetpal, you may be misunderstood the concept.
I agree with your point (interface can't implement another interface).
But I'm not implementing interface with another interface. I just extending the interface with another interface.